# Extracting URL from SoundCloud using Python

Tags: python

My goal is to pull the **tracks** and **playlist** from specific artists on soundcloud (e.g. lil wayne) from their soundcloud url using Python 2.7.9. I have tried the following code taken from https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python

```
import soundcloud

client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='xxx')

tracks = client.get('/tracks', limit=10)
for track in tracks:
    print track.title    
app = client.get('/tracks/30709985')
print app.permalink_url
```

I have tried changing `tracks = client.get('lilwayne/tracks', limit=10)` and changing `app = client.get('/lilwayne/tracks')`but I get the following **Traceback**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/er/Desktop/Soundcloud.py", line 7, in <module>
    tracks = client.get('lilwayne/tracks', limit=10)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/soundcloud/client.py", line 133, in _request
    return wrapped_resource(make_request(method, url, kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/soundcloud/request.py", line 148, in make_request
    result.raise_for_status()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 844, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api.soundcloud.com/lilwayne/tracks?limit=10&client_id=XXX
```

Question: In order to pull the tracks of specific artist on soundcloud, do I alter the content of `client.get()` or any suggestions?

Comment: "this doesn't work" - what does it do? See [mcve]

Comment: @WayneWerner     I get many error messages (line 7, 133, 148, 844) (not sure why I get errors on lines that don't exist.)     I also get an 
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api.soundcloud.com/lilwayne/tracks?limit=10&client_id=603498xxx

Comment: It seems that there is no tracks following this link [/lilwayne/tracks](https://soundcloud.com/lilwayne/tracks)

Comment: @AdrienLeber I just checked on the following link https://soundcloud.com/lilwayne/tracks and there are tracks available on the site

Comment: @ER_18 post the full text of your traceback (though if your client ID is present, you should probably mask that?)

Comment: @AdrienLeber I tried changing track client.get('https://soundcloud.com/lilwayne/tracks', limit=10) and changing app = client.get('https://soundcloud.com/lilwayne/tracks') but I get a different error :   for track in tracks:
TypeError: 'Resource' object is not iterable

Comment: @WayneWerner Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/er/Desktop/Soundcloud.py", line 7, in <module>
    tracks = client.get('lilwayne/tracks', limit=10)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/soundcloud/client.py", line 133, in _request
    return wrapped_resource(make_request(method, url, kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/soundcloud/request.py", line 148, in make_request
    result.raise_for_status()

Comment: @WayneWerner here is the rest of the traceback error:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 844, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api.soundcloud.com/lilwayne/tracks?limit=10&client_id=XXX

Comment: Did you registered your app as shown in the README of the GitHub repository ?

Comment: @ER_18 you can [edit] your question to include the traceback there. And should :)

Comment: @AdrienLeber I did (I just double checked and my app is registered under my company name)...

Comment: @WayneWerner ah right, good suggestion--done.

Comment: Why would you think this is a valid way to use the API? If you [read the api](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) it doesn't look like that's even remotely a valid way to use the API.

Comment: @WayneWerner I tried 'curl "https://soundcloud.com/a-tribe-called-red/tracks?client_id=XXX' per https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks but it looks like this is for the terminal not python

Comment: @ER_18 does that work? If it does, then you can plug that url into requests and it should work. If not, something very strange is happening.

Comment: @WayneWerner I imported requests and tried the URL listed above and it pulled the entire HTML script for a-tribe-called-red. So this is a good start. However, I'm still trying to find the code to specifically extract the URL for all his tracks...

Comment: Look at the API docs, but I don't think that you can

Comment: @WayneWerner do you mean the API docs for soundcloud?

Comment: That's who you're getting information from, right? Who else would you get info from?